# how to insert data to dataset

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this making table:

```
DataTable WorkTbl()
        {
            DataTable Work= new DataTable("Work"); //Table Name
            DataColumn MAC = new DataColumn("MAC", typeof(string));
            DataColumn ID_OLD = new DataColumn("ID_OLD", typeof(string));

            Work.Columns.Add(MAC);
            Work.Columns.Add(ID_OLD);
            return Work;
        }
```

how to insert data to this table and how to convert this table to Dataset ?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t31h6yhs.aspx will help you

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

```
DataRow workRow = workTable.NewRow();
```

You then can manipulate the newly added row using an index or the column name, as shown in the following example.

```
workRow["CustLName"] = "Smith";
workRow[1] = "Smith";


DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet("CustomerOrders");

DataTable ordersTable = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Orders");

DataColumn pkOrderID = 
    ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(Int32));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderQuantity", typeof(Int32));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));

ordersTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { pkOrderID };
```